# javascript config file for openlayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers, configuration-files

I am new to OpenLayers. I am trying to figure out what is the best way to have a configuration file for the map I am creating.

For example, I am creating a map with the following style :

```
    var defaultStyle = new OpenLayers.Style(
                        {
                            pointRadius: 10,
                            fillColor: "yellow",
                            strokeColor:"#0500bd", 
                            strokeWidth:2,
                            fillOpacity:0.4,
                            labelXOffset: "${xOffset}",
                            labelYOffset: "${yOffset}",
                            labelAlign: "${align}"
                        });
```

I would like to have the `pointRadius` and `fillColor` in a config file so I don't have to modify my source code but just the config file.

Shall I create a JS file; config.js with the following content:

```
      var config = {
           map:{
               style: {
                   pointRadius: 10,
                   fillColor: "yellow"
               },
           },
      };
```

And then, in my other JS that create the style, does:

```
    var defaultStyle = new OpenLayers.Style(
    {
        pointRadius: config.map.style.pointRadius,
            fillColor: config.map.style.fillColor,
        strokeColor:"#0500bd", 
        strokeWidth:2,
        fillOpacity:0.4,
                    labelXOffset: "${xOffset}",
            labelYOffset: "${yOffset}",
        labelAlign: "${align}"
    });
```

What is recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot say what is "recommended". However Your solution is very similar to the way we do it on our current project. We have been doing like that for over a year have had a lot of success.
We save the configuration in a database as a JSON array, and then allow JS to parse the array.

Also you can then use the OpenLayers.Util.extend function to extend your style:

```
var config = {
       map:{
           style: {
               pointRadius: 10,
               fillColor: "yellow"
           },
       },
  };

var defaultStyle = new OpenLayers.Style(OpenLayers.Util.extend({
       strokeColor:"#0500bd", 
       strokeWidth:2,
       fillOpacity:0.4,
       labelXOffset: "${xOffset}",
       labelYOffset: "${yOffset}",
       labelAlign: "${align}"
},config.map.style));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
var config = {
  default_map_style: {
    pointRadius: 10,
    fillColor: 'yellow'
  }
};
```

And then instead of using it one by one, I would just extend the default map style object with additional properties that I want to use on the fly like so:

```
var defaultStyle = new OpenLayers.Style(
  $.extend({}, config.default_map_style, {
    strokeColor: '#0500bd'
  }
);
```

I'm using [jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) above but you can find another implementation of extend in [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) or [Lo-dash](http://lodash.com/) if you'd rather not use jQuery. Note that it is important we pass a new object as the first parameter of extend as we don't want to change the `default_map_style` object.